# How to read the zeroth address of ROM connected on SPI bus?

Tags: c, embedded-linux, 8051

My master is is an ARM9 processor.

I want to read the zeroth address of internal ROM of an 8051 connected on SPI bus?

Can I use `read()` system call to do it? As I wanted it in user space, can I use `mmap()`
system call for that?

Answer (score 0):

The `read()` system call will call into the read routine of a device driver you previously opened with the `open()` system call; if you have a driver that provides access to your 8051 then you can use it according to however it has been implemented.

If you don't have a driver, using `mmap()` is an option if you have permission to map physical memory into your memory space, and if you know the proper register locations to configure (if needed), read and write to your SPI device. If you don't know those register locations (or communication protocol), you'll need to read your specific CPU manual (not a generic ARM9 manual, but something exact to your manufacturer/model) to get the information you need.

You'll also need to know the communication protocol used by the 8051 to send it an appropriate SPI command.